# Correct Syntax for MySQL Left join

Tags: mysql

I'm new to ***inner join*** and ***left join*** , Hope somebody can help me with this ..

I have 3 tables ..

1. Shirts
2. Colors
3. Prices

**Shirts:**

> sid  |   name 
>   `------------` 
>   01  |  Sample1 
>   02  |  Sample2

**Colors**

> sid |  color | color_id
>   `------------` 
>   01 |    red   | 900
>  
>   02 |  green | 090

**Prices:**

> sid   |   price
>   `------------` 
>   01   |  100 
>   02   |  100

**My query is:**

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid`
WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

What I would like to achieve is:

> sid |    name    | color   | price
>   `----------------------` 
>   02 |  Sample2  | green | 100

What I get is:

> sid  |    name    | color | price
>   `----------------------` 
>   null |     null      |  null  | null

I know there must be wrong with my query .. So can anyone please tell me what is the right query for that ?

Comment: Can problem be in column `GENDB_ID`? Must there be column Prices.SID?

Comment: your query is working just fine. I'm getting the proper results,same as you have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're new to inner join and left join, I will get you quickly review.

First, change your query to look like this (you wrong with the field which participate in ON filter)

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid`     //Change this.
WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

Beside this, when you use `left join` it does matter which columns you put in `where` condition (columns from left or right table).

To get correct and expected result, if you must filter your query by columns from RIGHT table (in your case `Prices` table), then that condition put in `ON` filter, not in `WHERE` filter.

Example:

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid`     
WHERE `Prices`.`price`= 100             //This can be wrong
```

Corrected:

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid` AND  `Prices`.`price`= 100   //Correct.
//WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use:

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid`
WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

`Prices`.`GENDB_ID` is not a valid field or is not what you have to use (I suppose).

Comment: What is the type of sid? Are they all integers or texts or other?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. This part

```
`on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`GENDB_ID
```

looks incorrect. Try instead:

```
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid` AND  `Prices`.`price`= 100   //Change this part.
WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    `Shirts`.*, 
    `Colors`.`color`,
    `Prices`.`price` 
FROM 
    `Shirts` INNER JOIN `Colors` on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
     JOIN `Prices` on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid` 
WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT `Shirts`.*, `Colors`.`color`, `Prices`.`price` FROM `Shirts`
INNER JOIN `Colors`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Colors`.`sid`
LEFT JOIN `Prices`
on `Shirts`.`sid` = `Prices`.`sid`
WHERE `Shirts`.`sid`='02'
```

The reason you are getting an all null row is the `GENDB_ID` you are including in your join.

The different between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` is that an `INNER JOIN` will exclude any join combination between the two tables which doesn't result in a match while `LEFT JOIN` will force a row even if there is no match.

An example:

**Shirts**

```
sid  |   name 
------------ 
01  | Sample1 
02  | Sample2
```

**Colors**

```
sid |  color | color_id
------------ 
01 |    red | 900
03 |  green | 090
```

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM Shirts INNER JOIN Colors ON Shirts.sid = Colors.sid

sid |   name  | color | color_id
---------------------------------
01  | Sample1 |  red  | 900
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM Shirts LEFT JOIN Colors ON Shirts.sid = Colors.sid

sid |   name  | color | color_id
---------------------------------
01  | Sample1 |  red  | 900
02  | Sample2 |  null | null
```

So in your example you are forcing a row with `LEFT JOIN` which matches an non-existant condition `GENDB_ID` which leads to a row with only null values for all columns in the row.

[This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) may also help.

Hope this helps!